# How to create a scrollable list for Watch OS that has a fixed size?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, watchkit, watchos

I'm a beginner to Watch OS programming (I'm using Storyboard) and would like some help with scrollable lists.

I need to create a scrollable list of numbers (e.g. from 1 to 20) that changes when user uses scrolls with the crown. I know how to create it using a Table, but the problem is, I don't know how to contain it to a single area.

I have added a screenshot of the "Sleep Cycle" app that has a similar feature. I would like to do the exact same thing, but instead of time, I need to show a list of numbers.

[image: Sleep Cycle]

Edit: Another example would be "Zero" where the hours field is scrollable:
[image: Zero]

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this library and try to customize it as per your use case:

https://github.com/calda/WatchKitTimePicker

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I needed to use WKPickerItem instead of a table!